# Share volumes between docker services

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to build two services with docker-composer. First service (application) is a simple volume container and the second (php-pm) is a PHP Process Manager. The problem is that my second service try to access Symfony folder that is shared by the first service. For some reason the folder not exists until both services was created.

docker-compose.yml

```
application:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
      - /home/Projects/symfony-pm:/var/www/symfony-pm
      - /home/Projects/symfony-pm/app/logs:/var/www/symfony-pm/app/logs
php-pm:
    build: ./
    dockerfile: dockerfile-php-pm
    ports:
      - 9999:9000
    volumes_from:
      - application
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

second service dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

#INSTALL PHP AND HIS DEPENDENCIES
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y php7.0-cgi php-xml && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php /usr/bin/php7.0-cgi

#INSTALL COMPOSER
RUN apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

#INSTALL PPM
RUN apt-get install -y git && \
    cd var && \
    git clone https://github.com/php-pm/php-pm.git && \
    cd php-pm && \
    composer install && \
    ln -s `pwd`/bin/ppm /usr/local/bin/ppm


#This folder doesn't exist, why??
RUN cd /var/www/symfony-pm && /
    composer require php-pm/php-pm:dev-master && /
    composer require php-pm/httpkernel-adapter:dev-master && /
    composer install
```

The last command doesn't work.
errors message cannot access '/var/www/symfony-pm': No such file or directory.

The directory exists because I've checked after both services was built.

Comment: Where is your dockerfile ?

Answer (score 0):

The folder doesn't exist because `volumes_from` mounts the directory when you start the container. But you try to access it during build of the container image.

What I would do is [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy) the contents of `/home/Projects/symfony-pm` during build time:

```
COPY /home/Projects/symfony-pm /var/www/symfony-pm
RUN composer require ...
```

Now every time you update your app you would need to rebuild the image.

Another possibility is to have `composer` run on container startup using [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint):

`entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/symfony-pm && composer ...
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```